# R seq function between item 1 and 2, then between 2 and 3 of a vector

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I have a vector `c(5, 10, 15)` and would like to use something like the seq function to created a new vector: `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`. This is how I would do it now, but it seems ineloquent at best. In the final (functional) form, I would need to increment by any given number, not necessarily units of 1.

```
original_vec <- c(5, 10, 15)
new_vec <- unique(c(seq(original_vec[1],original_vec[2],1),seq(original_vec[2],original_vec[3],1)))
> new_vec
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Is there a way (I'm sure there is!) to use an apply or similar function to apply a sequence across multiple items in a vector, also without repeating the number in the middle (in the case above, 10 would be repeated, if not for the `unique` function call.

Edit: Some other possible scenarios might include changing `c(1,5,7,10,12)` to `1,1.5,2,2.5 ... 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12`, or `c(1,7,4)` where the price increases and then decreases by an interval.

The answer may be totally obvious and I just can't quite figure it out. I have looked at manuals and conducted searched for the answer already. Thank you!

Comment: I find some edge cases for this.  What if the values are not always increasing?

Comment: Why not `seq(min(original_vec), max(original_vec))` ?

Comment: @akrun great point. In a case like c(10, 15, 10), I'd want in that case for the values to increase between points a and b, then to decrease from b to c. However, in my circumstance such an edge-case is unlikely

Comment: @RonakShah thats a great solution... need to think more on this

Comment: @RonakShah I've considered that the mid point might not even be relevant. I have to put some more thought into possible cases where it might be

Comment: Could you update your post with some possible scenarios..

Comment: @akrun Sure, I've added two above.

Comment: @PatrickWilliams  Thank you for adding those.  As I am not a guy who wants to get points at any cost, I will leave it for those who wants it.

Comment: @akrun if you have an answer, I'd love to see it. I'm not here to receive or give points for points-sake :D

Comment: It is still not clear about all the edge cases.  If it is alll increasing, may be `unique(unlist(Map(`:`, v1[-length(v1)], v1[-1])))` where `v1 <- c(5, 10, 15)`

Comment: @PatrickWilliams It looks like ronak-shah's answer should work for you. In instances where your step is different from 1, use the by argument: `seq(min(original_vec), max(original_vec), by=0.5)` for example. This will work for monotic sequences with equal steps. There are questions about unequal steps.

Comment: Thanks to all for the discussion. While I would still like an answer to my question from intellectual curiosity (taking into account the edge cases), my immediate needs have been filled!

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't the answer to my original question, after discussing with my colleague, we don't have cases where seq(min(original_vec), max(original_vec), by=0.5), wouldn't work, so that's the simplest answer.

However, a more generalized answer might be:

```
interval = 1
seq(original_vec[1], original_vec[length(original_vec)], by = interval)
```

Edit: Just thought I'd go ahead and include the finished product, which includes the seq value in a larger context and work for increasing values AND for cases where values change direction. The use case is the linear interpolation of utilities, given original prices and utilities.

```
orig_price <- c(2,4,6)
orig_utils <- c(2,1,-3)

utility.expansion = function(x, y, by=1){
  #x = original price, y = original utilities
  require(zoo)
  new_price <- seq(x[1],x[length(x)],by)
  temp_ind <- new_price %in% x
  new_utils <- rep(NA,length(new_price))
  new_utils[temp_ind] <- y
  new_utils <- na.approx(new_utils)
  return(list("new price"=new_price,"new utilities"=new_utils))
}
```